# Eclipse terminates without running program and shows 0 erros, 0 warnings

Tags: java, eclipse-neon

My Eclipse Neon doesn't run any program. I even tried running the simple "Hello World" program however after a few seconds the word `<terminated>` appears on top of the console and nothing shows up inside the console. I am hoping for some solutions.

```java
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you run the program?

Comment: Tried every way possible. Nothing works. I tried runniing the program by just pressing the run button on the top as well as clicking the down arrow beside the run and selecting class name.

Comment: I recommend you delete the run configuration. Click the arrow next to run, click "Run Configurations" and delete the config on the left side using the red X at the top left. Then close that window, right click your code, select "Run As" -> "Java Application". That creates a new run configuration which hopefully works.